# Create models from json feed in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I am making a django app to browse available products at different markets. I am getting data for my models from a JSON url feed, I am not sure on the best approach to turn this data into models as the feed for a single market can contain upwards of 50k items.

Models - feel free to suggest any improvements on these

```
# Details of a sellable products
class Product(models.Model):
    item = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

# Market where products can be bought, some markets will cater to multiple suburbs.
class Market(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

# Nearby suburbs can share the one market
class Suburb(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

# Actual product for sale
class ProductForSale(models.Model):
    sale = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True )
```

Feed of markets products example

```
"market_products": [
    {
        "id":11654,
        "item":123,
        "owner":"Bob",
        "suburb":"Springvale",
        "cost":3,
        "quantity":1,

    },
    {
        "id":11655,
        "item":123,
        "owner":"Sarah",
        "suburb":"Sunnyville",
        "cost":5,
        "quantity":2,

    },
```

This is how I am trying to populate my ProductForSale models - I don't know if this is the correct approach for the Product FK, or how to link the suburb to its Market FK

```
    markets = Market.objects.all()
    for market in markets:
        url = "jsonurl"
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        for entry in data['market_products']:
                new_product_sale = ProductForSale.objects.create(
                    product = Product.objects.get(item=entry['item']),
                    cost = entry['cost'],
                    owner = entry['owner'],
                    quantity = entry['quantity']
                )
                new_product_sale.save()
```

Is there a point where I should create a seperate model for each markets products, or is it fine to house them all in the one model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with one model for all market products, have not come against any issues in doing so as of yet.